# Surjectivity of a function that maps a 3rd-degree or less polynomial to the set of real numbers.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let the function $T\colon P_3\to\Bbb R$ be defined by
$$T(p)=\int_0^1 p(x) \mathrm{d}x$$
Every real number has at least one element in $P_3$ mapped to it through the function $T$, so I know that this function is surjective. I am wondering how to prove that all real numbers can be mapped by the definite integral of a polynomial of at most degree $3$.

Comment: Why does my mathjax never format properly? Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and consider the constant polynomial $p(x) = a$.  Then

$$
T(p) \;\; =\;\; \int_0^1 p(x)dx \;\; =\;\; a \int_0^1dx \;\; =\;\; a.
$$

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.